# What is $H_0^1$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a book and it says that the $H_0^1(\Omega)$ space is defined as "the completion of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ w.r.t the Sobolev norm $\| \cdot \|_1$, where $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is the space of infinitely differentiable functions which are nonzero only on a compact subset of $\Omega$".

Can I simply understand the $H_0^1(\Omega)$ space as the space of all functions $u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ whose value on the boundary of $\Omega$ is $0$ ($u\big |_{\partial\Omega}=0$)?

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively you can, provided that $\partial \Omega$ is smooth enough.

In [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) book, page 273, theorem 2 exactly proves the statement you want. I don't know how much your background is of Sobolev space, but I suggest to read it. It is not hard. (Actually I would say it is really a good exercise to proof!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm going to have a look at that book.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the functions in $H^1_0$ are defined a.e, so the "value at boundary" is not something immediatly defined. You can makes sense of a value at the boundary of function in $H^1$ with the [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator)  if $\partial \Omega$ is smooth enough, but you need to do some work. The definition by the completion of $C^{\infty}_0$ gives you immediatly a well defined space.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to work on this topic more to get what you've pointed out.