If $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ then $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$?
Suppose that $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a set. Also, suppose that $u$ vanishes at the boundary(For example, the trace of $u$ at $\partial \Omega$(the boundary of $\Omega$) vanishes). Then, is it necessarily true that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$?
I initially thought it should be because I only know how to define $\Delta u$ for $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Even though, I wondered if there is any other way.
I thank you in advance!

What is your interpretation of "vanishes at the boundary"? Here $u$ is defined on an open set $\Omega$ and not necessarily even defined on $\partial \Omega$.

@UmbertoP.  I apologize for the confusion. I meant the analogous concept with $H_0^1$. In other words, the closure of $C_0^\infty$ (The space of smooth functions with the compact domains) with respect to $L^2$ norm. I will edit my question.

The closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ is just $L^2(\Omega)$. On the other hand, the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ is $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

I think what you really want to say is that the trace of $u$ on $\partial \Omega$ vanishes (though you might need some regularity for $\partial \Omega$).

@SeverinSchraven Thank you for the comment! You are right! I edited. Thank you again

If your boundary is nice enough, then $u\in H_0^1$ is the same as $u\in H^1$ and the trace vanishing on the boundary (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365657/what-is-h-01-space). Is your problem that you would like to prove that if $u$ solves the PDE that $u\in H^1$?

@SeverinSchraven Thank you for the comment! My question has nothing to do with PDE. I have seen that people define Laplacian operator $\Delta$ unbounded operator on $L^2$ or $H_0^1$ with $|\Delta u |_{L^2}<\infty$. Some literature define it on $L^2$ and some define on $H_0^1$. I wondered if they are equivalent.

There are various ways of defining the Laplacian and they are not equivalent. You can see this for example in $d=1$ for an interval. The Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions is not the same as the one with Neumann boundary conditions (the second has zero as an eigenvalue wheras the first does not).

The point is that for bounded domains the Laplacian on $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is not essentially self-adjoint, i.e. this symmetric operator has multiple inequivalent self-adjoint extensions.

@SeverinSchraven I think this link(https://mathoverflow.net/q/335952/127918) contains the answer for my question. I am not 100 sure as it does not involve vanishing boundary.  I need to come back after take a deep look.

The answer you link is essentially discussing the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$ in which case the symmetric operator $-\Delta$ on $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ has only one unique extension. The case of bounded $\Omega$ is very different, there the chosen boundary conditions make a huge difference.

When thinking about these types of problems it can help to avoid the formalism of Sobolev spaces and rather use your intuition about smooth functions.  If $u$ is a smooth function on $\Omega$ must it vanish on the boundary of $\Omega$?
A first step would be to consider $u=1$.

Thank you for your answer. I realized that I was clumsy when I wrote the question. I implicitly assumed that the function $u$ vanishes at the boundary. I just edited the question. I apologize for the mistake.
